# EditText wont regain focus after softKeyboard is hidden - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

The title is pretty explanatory. I have an EditText and once the activity begins it gains focus. But when I hide the keyboard or push enter and the keyboard hides itself I can't regain focus on the EditText. Here is my xml code.

```
  <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="15dip"
android:hint="Edit"
android:singleLine="true"
android:lines="1"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="left"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:textStyle="italic"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:padding="5dip"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **android:focusableInTouchMode="true"*** and try again!